# PyQGIS: Importing own modules results in ModuleNotFoundError or KeyError

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I've installed QGis 3 on Mac using osgeo4mac and wrote a script in the Processing Script Editor. The script works fine but when I try to divide it into several modules, I get an error when importing them.

`import module_name` 
or
`from module_name import function_name`

results in `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Relative import using `import .module_name` results in `KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"`

All scripts (main.py, module_name.py etc.) are in the same folder. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I had the same problem, solved it by extending sys.path with the script directory before importing. A better way will be to build a processing plugin, where you can use local imports.

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to Andreas Müller by adding:
`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.expanduser('~/') + 'path/to/scripts/folder')` to the main script before importing modules.